# .Net Core Hosting Bundle on 2012 Server R2 , effect of X86 Packages installing

Tags: iis-8.5

I am following along  [instructions to deploy a .netcore api to IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Only after I followed the instruction to install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle did I read

```
To prevent the installer from installing x86 packages on an x64 OS,
run the installer from an administrator command prompt with the switch 
OPT_NO_X86=1.
```

Should I be worried that I did not do that?

Why did the instruction come so late in the steps to follow?

Comment: `OPT_NO_X86` is optional. Typical IIS extensions (like this one) should install itself to both x64 and x86 of IIS worker processes, while `OPT_NO_X86` gives the option to skip x86. However, skipping x86 can lead to issues if you must run IIS x86 worker process for your ASP.NET Core app. Unless your machine is really running out of resources, you should leave it as it right now.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi would you care to write that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPT_NO_X86` is optional.

Typical IIS extensions (like this one) should install themselves to both x64 and x86 of IIS worker processes, while `OPT_NO_X86` gives the option to skip x86.

However, skipping x86 can lead to issues if you must run IIS x86 worker process for your ASP.NET Core app.

Unless your machine is really running out of resources, you should leave it as it right now.